# Clicking iAd restart the whole game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad

I am working on a  sprite kit game project and I got an issue on iAd, the Ad works fine, till I not click the ad. But when i click the ad it restart my whole game, and I am using only one iAd for my entire game.

The implementation of iAd is in my UIViewController class.

I know these two methods related to my issue but I don't know how to use them:

```
-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave


-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

I've tried every thing I know, but nothing comes out.

Comment: Check if viewWillLayoutSubviews tests for skView.scene == nil before presenting the scene. If there's no such check then you are presenting the first scene every time viewWillLayoutSubviews runs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it **works**, but there is one more issue occurred. I am using UISlider for volume in my game, if UISlider is on  screen and then i touch the ad and then return to game it still there and never disappear even if i click to back button of my game, it also disappear when iAd refresh, but it appear when i again click to volume button. The UISlider is implemented in the same UIViewController class.